# error while linking libraries: libboost_system

Tags: c++, boost, g++, mingw, boost-asio

I am trying to run some basic server/client software from the Boost:Asio tutorials. The application works fine on the linux box, but when I try to compile the code on my windows box (mingw) I am unable to link the boost_system library.

g++ -I C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost server.cpp -o server.exe -lpthread -lboost_system

How do I link boost_system in on my windows box?

Error:

```
c:\Users\me\Documents\cpp\asioTest>g++ -I C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost-1_52\ asioServer.cpp -lboost_system

In file included from C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost-1_52/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:18:0,
             from C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost-1_52/boost/asio.hpp:20,
             from asioServer.cpp:15:
C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost-1_52/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:205:5: warning:
#warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. [-Wcpp]
C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost-1_52/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:206:5: warning:
#warning For example, add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line. [-Wcpp]
C:\boost_1_52_0\include\boost-1_52/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:207:5: warning:
#warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target). [-Wcpp]
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: So where *is* the library in question?  Do you just need to add a -L path to your command line?

Comment: Like Carl said, you specify the path to the includes but not the libs for boost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost::system link error on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260675/boostsystem-link-error-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Not really a duplicate... I know how to link using g++, but the library is not being found when I use windows.

Comment: @Jeff if you know how, then why is `-L /path/to/libraries` missing on your link line? I assume it is in the same location as the boost headers, ex: `-L C:\boost_1_52_0\lib`